# Using d3 defer in Angular model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have a working d3 choropleth that has the following chunk of code:

```
// Load data
.defer(d3.csv, data, function(d) { 
  rateById.set(d.state, +d.count); 
})
```

This is working fine.  Problem is, now I'm trying to pass in data just as an array of objects.  A format such as:

```
[
 {
   id: 1,
   count: 200 
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   count: 100
 }
]
```

How can I change my `.defer` call to support this new data format?

Comment: try to store the object in a variable named data and while passing data to defer function do a JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: You don't even need the stringify. Just store the data in a variable with the name that you're using in the callback.